# R - function like COUNTIFS

Tags: r, excel, data-manipulation

I'm looking for R's version of Excel's "COUNTIFS" function

Scenario:

> I have two columns full of values, I want to add a column that would store
>   count of records that have same values in Col1 and Col2

It's like having to primary key split in two columns *I guess*

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 ColNew
A1   B1   EPP  2
A1   B2   EPP  1
A1   B1   EPP  2
```

In Excel i got it to work using below formula

> =COUNTIFS(C:C,$C2,A:A,$A2,E:E,$E$2)>1

But it actually returned `TRUE` or `FALSE` instead of numbers

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr` has a function called `add_count` that does just that:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Col1,Col2) %>%
  add_count

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
# # Groups:   Col1, Col2 [2]
#    Col1  Col2  Col3     n
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1    A1    B1   EPP     2
# 2    A1    B2   EPP     1
# 3    A1    B1   EPP     2
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="Col1 Col2 Col3
A1   B1   EPP
A1   B2   EPP
A1   B1   EPP",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: I haven't seen a function called in a pipe without parentheses at the end, but I just tried it and it works. Is `add_count` unique or is it just because it doesn't require additional arguments?

Comment: When there are no arguments other than 1st argument and default you don't need them. I read it's good practice to put them anyway but I prefer not to. If you precede the function name by the package name as in `dplyr::add_count` you will need parentheses though

Answer (score 6):

`ave` might be a very useful function in this case:

```
df$ColNew <- ave(rep(1, nrow(df)), df$Col1, df$Col2, FUN = length)

df
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 ColNew
#1   A1   B1  EPP      2
#2   A1   B2  EPP      1
#3   A1   B1  EPP      2
```

Answer (score 5):

`dplyr` and `data.table` are two popular packages that make doing things "by group" very easy.

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% group_by(Col1, Col2) %>% mutate(ColNew = n())
```

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)
df[, ColNew := .N, by = .(Col1, Col2)]
```

Comment: Im getting and error:
Error: This function should not be called directly

Comment: Sounds like you maybe loaded the `plyr` library after the `dplyr` library - `plyr` uses some of the same function names (like `mutate`), but with older versions, and if the `plyr` version gets used with `dplyr` it causes errors like that. You can specify `dplyr::mutate` to make sure you get the right version, or you can just make sure that *if* you load both `plyr` and `dplyr` packages, load `plyr` first.

Comment: Ah, that was an issue. Thank you for explaining, Ill keep that in mind for the future

Answer (score 4):

```
transform(dat,col=ave(do.call(paste,dat),Col2,Col3,FUN = length))
  Col1 Col2 Col3 col
1   A1   B1  EPP   2
2   A1   B2  EPP   1
3   A1   B1  EPP   2
```

Comment: It's not documented, but I believe `ave` coerces the result to the same type as the input. So `col` will be character. You could coerce the result to be the type you want or just pass the type you as the input.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is `df`, then please try:

```
library(plyr)
counts <- ddply(df, .(df$Col1, df$Col2), nrow)
names(counts) <- c("Col1", "Col2", "Freq")
```

Could you please try this as an alternative solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, list(Freq =.N), by=list(Col1,Col2)]
```

According to the data provided in the question, I was expecting resultset like:

```
Col1 Col2 Freq
A1   B1   2
A1   B2   1
```

Comment: It returns less than half of the records that was in file, is it returning only unique values? what if i would like to keep them all?

Comment: @Doniu Hmm, it is calculating the frequency by grouping by Col1 and Col2, so I did not expect to see the same total number of rows in your output. Edited my answer adding an alternative solution